# How do I upload images in php after I have already saved data from the form1 and images are uploaded in form2

Tags: php, forms

I have a html page, with a form and image upload,
I want to update the database with the images once uploaded, the two form work well individually, but I need to link the form-data to the uploaded images in the database.

kindly help with logic, I am considering using sessions

Comment: Consider adding your attempts

Answer (score 1):

You can use session as you mentioned or you can updated the relevant record with the next form details.

Say for example, once first form is filled and submited by the user, add those details in database and get the ID of that record.
When the second form is submited by the user, update the same record which you have already added for form 1.

So in database you will have only one record for both the forms with all relavent detials.

Comment: Kindly expound on this with an example. the images are not going to be saved to the database, only the image names. as saving images as BLOBs seems to defy good SEO practices

Comment: SEO has nothing to do with this - as you have to deliver the images through your webserver, nobody will see whether they came from a database or the filesystem

Comment: Sammy Caesar, its not needed to save the images as blobs. You can move the uploaded images to any storage media like s3 or even into your local server in any specific asserts folder and save the name alone in db.

Comment: Say you have 2 forms.

Form 1  :
`Name, Email`

Form 2  :
`Image Upload`

User Table Fields :
`id, name , email, image`

Once form 1 is submitted, update the fields in user table.
`id : 1, name :MYNAME, email : MYEMAIL, image:_NULL_ `
(only email and name will get updated)

Now pass the value of this record id to next form. 
Once second form is submitted, update the image field

`id: 1, name : MYNAME, email : MYEMAL, image: MY_IMAGE_NAME` (Only image will get updated in this case)
The image can be uploaded to s3  or moved to local folder and use its path to store in db

Answer (score 0):

- You could save your images in the session if you don't want to save them in the database (which, by the way, might not be a good idea), this avoids putting stuff in the database that is not yet finally processed (as I understand: this happens when the other form is submitted?)
- You could put them in a table for "temporary images" which are not yet processed finally and just keep track of the IDs through the session

Comment: I get what you are saying, my challenge is on the relational part of the logic, since the first form data is already posted and the page refreshes.. should I have the session hold the data that I will use to link the two tables?